# How can I use the new DI to inject an ILogger into an Azure Function using IWebJobsStartup?

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am using `Azure Function` v2. Here is my function that uses the constructor injection:

```
public sealed class FindAccountFunction
{
    private readonly IAccountWorkflow m_accountWorkflow;

    private readonly IMapper m_mapper;

    private readonly ILogger m_logger;

    public FindAccountFunction(ILogger logger, IMapper mapper, IAccountWorkflow accountWorkflow)
    {
        m_logger = logger;
        m_mapper = mapper;
        m_accountWorkflow = accountWorkflow;
    }

    [FunctionName("FindAccount")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, Verbs.Get, Route = "v1/accounts/")] HttpRequest httpRequest, ILogger logger)
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

I am declaring all the dependencies that I want to inject into my Azure Function in the Startup class that derives from `IWebJobsStartup`:

```
    public sealed class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder webJobsBuilder)
        {
            //  Registers the application settings' class.
            webJobsBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IApplicationSettings, ApplicationSettings>();

            //  ** Registers the ILogger instance **
            //  ** ?? **

            //  Registers the IMapper instance for the contracts.
            var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new MyProfile()));

     webJobsBuilder.Services.AddSingleton(mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper());

            // Registers custom services.
            webJobsBuilder.Services.AddTransient<IStorageService, StorageService>();

            webJobsBuilder.Services.AddTransient<IAccountWorkflow, AccountWorkflow>();
        }
   }
```

The Azure Function calls other injected services that do depends on the ILogger as well, such as the `IAccountWorkflow`:

```
public sealed class AccountWorkflow : IAccountWorkflow
{  
    public AccountWorkflow(ILogger logger, IStorageService storageService)
    {
        if(logger is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the DI is unable to find any `ILogger` implementation and fails to resolve services since a null `ILogger` is injected.

**Question**

How can I setup the injection of the `ILogger` in `IWebJobsStartup`?

Comment: I thought functions were suppose to be static?

Comment: Oh man :) . I just discovered this today and it made my day. Now, we can remove the static keyword and do some sweet ctor injection. I just need to inject the freaking logger for it to be perfect :)

Comment: Oh, this is new? are there any docs I can research this?

Comment: @Nkosi this is part of the work for using DI in azure function. You can look at this issue : [Dependency Injection support for Functions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3736) . See the `Port changes to enable instance methods`

Comment: @Nkosi Hence instance methods are supported since v2.0.12265 of the runtime : [Azure Functions Runtime 2.0.12265](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.12265)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### UPDATE

Reference [Use dependency injection in .NET Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#registering-services)

> #### Registering services
>
> To register services, you can create a configure method and add components to an `IFunctionsHostBuilder`
>   instance. The Azure Functions host creates an `IFunctionsHostBuilder`
>   and passes it directly into your configured method.
>
> To register your configure method, you must add an assembly attribute
>   that specifies the type for your configure method using the
>   `FunctionsStartup` attribute.

So in this case

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]    
namespace MyNamespace {
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) {
            //  ** Registers the ILogger instance **
            builder.Services.AddLogging();

            //  Registers the application settings' class.
            //...

            //...omitted for brevity    
        }
    }
}
```

### ORIGINAL

I believe since you have access to the service collection, you should be able to add logging to it

```
public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder webJobsBuilder) {       

    //  ** Registers the ILogger instance **
    webJobsBuilder.Services.AddLogging();

    //OR
    //webJobsBuilder.Services.AddLogging(builder => {
    //    //...
    //});

    //  Registers the application settings' class.
    //...

    //...removed for brevity
}
```

and having an`ILoggerFactory` in the Function's constructor.

```
//...

//Ctor
public FindAccountFunction(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IMapper mapper, IAccountWorkflow accountWorkflow) {
    m_logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<FindAccountFunction>();
    m_mapper = mapper;
    m_accountWorkflow = accountWorkflow;
}

//...
```

Comment: I think this is somewhat outdated now, should use [FunctionsStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#registering-services) instead.

Comment: @Kapé that is correct. This would have been done before that version was released. Thank you for the reference link. I have updated answer to reflect recent version.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but I think `builder.Services.AddLogging();`is not required anymore as well? Seems to be set in the `Services` collection already.

Comment: Using the updated approach of leveraging `FunctionsStartup` is not working for me. I tried with and without `builder.Services.AddLogging`.

Comment: Using `ILogger<Name of constructor's class>` worked just fine.

Comment: @user3613932 yes the newer versions have logging added by default so using `ILogger<T>` should would out of the box.

Comment: If you don't see the logs in Azure Functions console, add to `host.json` the following code `"logging": {   "logLevel": {     "default": "Information"   } }`

Answer (score 27):

I managed to resolve this problem:

Injecting into my class as below:
MyClass.cs:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;

    public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Namespace.Startup))]   

namespace Namespace {    
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup 
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) 
    {
        builder.Services.AddLogging(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me. However, it's important to inject it like ```ILogger<MyClass> _logger``` instead of ```ILogger _logger```

Answer (score 15):

You should remove the call of `AddLogging` method from your startup class. The default logger is already setup by the azure function host.

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(StartUp))]
public class StartUp : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppSettings>();

        builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
    }
}

public MyFunction(IMyService service, ILogger<IMyService> logger)
{
    this.service = service;
    this.logger = logger;
}
```

Instance methods are now supported with azure function since [Azure Functions Runtime 2.0.12265](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.12265)

[image]

Comment: Hum... Still the same error. Do I have to use the generic version of ILogger?

Comment: Yep for me it works only with the generic version yesterday :)

Comment: I think only ILogger<> is registered with `services.AddLogging()`. See  [LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)

Comment: Looks like it does work. I will do more tests after work but it looks like you got it :)

Comment: I do not have any errors but I am not seeing the logs where I used to (In the Azure Function monitor sections or in App Insights)... Need more investigation to make sure it does work

Comment: I will mark this as an accepted answer because it does solve the crashing issue. I still do not see the logs in Application Insights like I used to but I will ask a question specifically for this new problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Kzrystof add to `host.json` the following code
```"logging": {
  "logLevel": {
    "default": "Information"
  }
}```

Answer (score 9):

In addition to registering the class in function Startup class, we would need to add the namespace in `host.json` file as well in order to log the messages to App insights. If we don't add it, it will simply log the message to console locally but when deployed on azure, it won't log anything and won't give any error either.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "FunctionProjectNameSpace.RegisteredClass": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Sample code here for reference - https://gist.github.com/nareshnagpal06/82c6b4df2a987087425c32adb58312c2

Answer (score 8):

You can add

```
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
```

without the need to add DI if you want to use IloggerFactory

Comment: I've tested all approaches listed here and this works with the least effort - just make sure you DI `ILogger<T>` into your function's ctor.