# Why is the ILogger injected in my Azure Function v2 missing the APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY?

Tags: c#, azure, logging, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function v2, like this:

```
public sealed class FindAccountFunction
{
    private readonly IAccountWorkflow m_accountWorkflow;

    public FindAccountFunction(ILogger<FindAccountFunction> logger)
    {
        m_logger = logger;
    }

    [FunctionName("FindAccount")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "GET", Route = "v1/accounts/")] HttpRequest httpRequest)
    {
        // Do stuff.
        m_logger.LogInformation("Duuuddde");
    }
}
```

As described in a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876798/how-can-i-use-the-new-di-to-inject-an-ilogger-into-an-azure-function-using-iwebj), the logger is being injected:

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

public sealed class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder webJobsBuilder)
    {
        // Registers other services...

        // -- UPDATE - The AddLogging must be called here --
        webJobsBuilder.Services.AddLogging();
    }
}
```

Then I trigger my function through an HTTP request and go to the Function's portal on Azure DevOps to see if the logs is actually printed:

[image: Azure Function's portal]

I only see the logs indicating that the function ran successfully however I do not see my log.

**Question**

Why is the `ILogger` injected in my Azure Function v2 missing the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`?

**Update**

When I look at the injected `ILogger`, I can see that the InstrumentationKey of the Application Insights Provider is not set. The same applies for a ctor injected ILogger, but also for the injected `ILogger` in the Run method.

[image: Instrumentation key]

For my local tests, the instrumentation key is declared in the `local.settings.json` file:

[image: local.settings.json]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got confused with different variants of setup (`ILogger` vs `ILoggerFactory` vs other stuff).

In my `Startup` class, it is correct to call `AddLogging` (with a minimum level or not, as long as it is defined somewhere here or in the `host.json` file).

```
using InjectionHttpClientFactory;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace InjectionHttpClientFactory
{
    public sealed class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder webJobsBuilder)
        {
            webJobsBuilder.Services.AddLogging();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Azure Function, I have an error if I specify `HttpClient` as a parameter:

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to
>   resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while
>   attempting to activate 'XXX'

However, it does work if I specify an `ILoggerFactory`. The instrumentation key property that was empty somehow has no impact.

I have updated the `host.json` file to include the logging information with the minimum severity level as well as configuration information for Application Insights:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 5
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

As mentioned in comments, Microsoft released an [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#registering-services) which introduces the `FunctionsStartup` class which should be the preferred way of doing this.

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton((s) => {
                return new CosmosClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COSMOSDB_CONNECTIONSTRING"));
            });
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, MyLoggerProvider>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is somewhat outdated now, should use [FunctionsStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#registering-services) instead.

Comment: What is the implementation of MyLoggerProvider?

Comment: @JoãoAntunes It is up to you to define your own provider. This specific code snippet comes from Microsoft's documentation (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#registering-services).

Answer (score 1):

```
    services.AddSingleton(context => 
        {
            var factory = context.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
            var loggingConfiguration = <get your app insights's instrumentation key from your configuration provider>;
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo
                    .ApplicationInsightsEvents(loggingConfiguration.ApplicationInsightsKey)
                    .CreateLogger();
            return factory.AddSerilog(logger).CreateLogger("MyLogger");
        });
```

Logger needs to be configured prior to ingest telemetry with your app-insights. Design Usage(Serilog) pattern may be different as this is just a stub to explain.

Answer (score -1):

Logger is passed as a function argument:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, Verbs.Get, Route = "v1/accounts/")] HttpRequest httpRequest, ILogger log)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The most recent runtime Azure Function enables the ILogger to be injected not only in the Function itself but in the injected services also. Even if I add the ILogger to the Run method itself, I will most likely have the same issue with the services: where will I see the logs from those services?

Comment: Ok. Did you had a look at https://github.com/Ruard/ProcsIT.Azure.Functions.DependencyInjection ?
I didn't tried it.

Comment: Does not seem to be related to my problem: it looks like a custom solution with a custom attribute named Inject. I am using services.AddLogging(); which is supposed to do all of this.