# Azure Function - Unable to log message to Application insights from service class

Tags: azure, logging, dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am facing issues in logging messages from the service class of Azure Function app. There are no issues in logging from the function class. I followed the solution mentioned on [Azure Functions - ILogger Logging across classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624192/azure-functions-ilogger-logging-across-classes) but cant figure out the issue.

**host.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "FunctionApp.Services.RestService": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

**RestService.cs**

```
public class RestService : IRestService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IRestService> _logger;
        public RestService(ILogger<IRestService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public async Task<RestResponse> SampleMethod()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("************************************TEST THIS WORK************************************","1212121212");
        }
    }
```

**IRestService.cs**

```
public interface IRestService
    {
        Task<RestResponse> SampleMethod(string url, string requestBody, string soapAction);
    }
```

I am calling the RestService class from the function app.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRestService, RestService>();
        }
    }
```

As mentioned earlier, the log messages from the function class appears in App Insight but not from the service class. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

You need to change **Host.json** file.

**host.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "Function": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Taken Code from (for Class, Interface class, Startup and main function) reference ([Link](https://gist.github.com/nareshnagpal06/82c6b4df2a987087425c32adb58312c2))

I have written similar code as you but changed **Host.json** code. Try to change hots.json and you will get output as I have got.

Comment: Did u verify in Application Insight?

Comment: Yes I did got Logs, Even I have kept local log output. You need to change host.json it will work

Comment: Surprising, I am neither getting logs in console nor in app insights. Tried the change recommended by you

Comment: Try with the Dowork code(i have given link of Github) and My Host.josn code, You will get Logs

Comment: I have copied exactly like that. I will review all my changes. Must be missing something

Comment: Try to create a new function app and do it from first

Comment: I am going mad. When I do it in a brand new project. It works but does not work in my current project

Comment: I am glad that it worked out, May be there are some changes you have done which are not suitable for this code I guess in your prev project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250344/discussion-between-tarun-bhatt-and-rithwikbojja).

Comment: @RithwikBojja, provide the function code, logger related class files code how you have configured the logger and Azure App Insights Screenshot.